# What does the parenthesized number in the "command" column mean for postgres processes?

Tags: linux, ps, top, postgresql

When I execute

`ps aux | grep postgres`

or *top | grep postgres*

I get all my postgres processes with some information, the last column (command) has the following structure:

```
postgres: username db ip_address(xxxxx) QUERY_TYPE
```

For example:

```
postgres: postgres test 192.168.0.100(33195) SELECT
```

What does this number means (33195)?

I'm having troubles with my database and I want to know if this information could help me. Some queries are taking too long.

It is some kind of process dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-ps.html),

> On most Unix platforms, PostgreSQL modifies its command title as reported by ps, so that individual server processes can readily be identified

It appears to me that the `33195` in your example is the port on the possibly-remote system `192.168.0.100` that has connected with the postgres server. Confirm with something like `netstat -an | grep 33195` .

Just found the [git repository for postgresql](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=summary) where I traced the behavior to the [DoBackend](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c;h=8c5eb5ae9046989904ba8620f544a8c8980cc6e4;hb=eb133197b63edf84b24a529f365902c46bc92e57#l1920) function, which updates the `ps` listing like this:

```
/*
 * Set process parameters for ps
 *
 * WARNING: On some platforms the environment will be moved around to
 * make room for the ps display string. So any references to
 * optarg or getenv() from above will be invalid after this call.
 * Better use strdup or something similar.
 */
init_ps_display(real_argc, real_argv, port->user, port->database,
                remote_host);
```

where remote_host was set earlier.

Comment: I might have stumbled onto the wrong git branch; see also [this](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c;h=24add74512fa2086d0044c6fc12dfbdbe7d776a3;hb=HEAD#l4101)